# Why is an array type written as if it was a list, in F#?

Tags: f#

with the following:

```
let a = "hello world".Split(' ')
```

the return type is a string array, but the type is written as:

> System.String[]

I'm not understanding why:

- you declare an array with `[| ... |]` but it is displayed as `[ ... ]` in the type
- you declare a list with `[ ... ]` but it is displayed as `x list` in the type

Another example:

```
([| 3 |]).GetType()
val it : System.Type =
  System.Int32[]
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: You should ask the people who made F# :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an inconsistency that is probably a result of the fact that F# is a .NET language.

- In F#, you want lists more often than arrays, so it makes sense to use a shorter syntax `[ ... ]` for lists and longer syntax `[| ... |]` for arrays.
- In .NET, array types are written as `System.Int32[]`. This is what you get from `GetType` and there is no way F# can override this, because it's coming from the .NET library.
- As for the type names, you can always use `'a list` and `'a array` if you want to write types explicitly.
- The most inconsistent features is the fact that you can write an array type such as `int[]` in F# too. I agree this is confusing. I think F# simply adopted the notation used in C# here. However, note that this also lets you define multi-dimensional arrays easily like `int[,]` and `int[,,]`. I don't think there is other syntax for multi-dimensional array types.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are reasons for this, but they're not very satisfying:

- **Types and values are not written the same way.** For example, a tuple type is written as `'A * 'B`, while a tuple value is written `(a, b)`. Some of us might've preferred `('A, 'B)` for the type as well, but F# is actually consistent with how product types/values are represented mathematically.
- **Lists are more fundamental to functional programming than arrays**, so it makes sense that fewer keystrokes are needed to write a list than to write an array.
- **F# inherited OCaml conventions, and adapted them to .NET**, sometimes awkwardly. The type of `[| 1; 2; 3 |]` in OCaml is `int array`. F# accepts the .NET/C# name `int[]` as well, which is confusing, but you can still use the  OCaml syntax in your code if you want: `let arr : int array = Array.empty`.